# How do i determine the first digit of a number without knowing the number of digits?c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, numbers, codeblocks, digits

For example, `42556`. How do I determine first digit if I don't know the number of digits in the number? I could't find an algorithm that suits me anywere! (I mean to determine the 4 in 42556)

Comment: @MikeDunlavey i thought that;s how i determine the last number( the 6)

Comment: @MikeDunlavey Won't that give you the last digit, the 6 in this case?

Comment: **last** in the title, **first** in the question = instant downvote.

Comment: I know you have an answer now. But, if I didn't know that way, I would convert to string and extract first character. But I realise that is not very good compared to the answers. 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `a` is the input number.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    long a = 42556;
    long num;
    num=floor(log10(a))+1; 
    //cout<<num<<" "<<"\n";  //prints the number of digits in the number

    cout<<a/(int)pow(10,num-1)<<"\n"; //prints the first digit
    cout<<a%10<<"\n";                 //prints the last digit

    return 0;
}
```

Live demo **[here](http://ideone.com/dNByEa)**.

Comment: Thanks to all of u for answering my question!

Comment: i saw u answerinfg a lot of questions latley on stack overflow

Comment: The +1, -1 operations are needless unless you uncomment out the commented line

Answer (score 2):

You could keep on dividing it by 10 until you've reached the last digit:

```
int lastDigit(int n) {
    n = abs(n); // Handle negative numbers
    int ret = n;
    while (n > 0) {
        ret = n % 10;
        n /= 10;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Iteratively divide by 10 until the result is less than 10.

```
num = 42556
while num > 9
    num = num / 10
```

Comment: Assuming the number is in base10

Answer (score 1):

All answers assumed you have an integer number. But generally, you can first get the integer form using the function `floor` from `<cmath>`, i.e.

```
#include <cmath>
int getlastdigit(double number)
{
    long long n = (long long)floor(number);
    while(n > 9)
        n /= 10;
    return n;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int firstdigit(int n) {
           int x = n;
          while(n != 0) {
             x = n%10;
             n = n/10;

          }
         return x;
    }
```

Comment: @DragosStamatin : There is a better way to thank on stack overflow. You can upvote/accept the answer

Comment: @drescherjm : Thanks for pointing this out. That was a silly mistake I made

Comment: (This still return a non-initialised value for argument `n`=0.)

Comment: @greybeard, could you please elaborate?  For `n=0`, the value of `x` would be `0`, which in turn is returned.